# How to merge separate files using TortoiseGit or bash

Tags: git, tortoisegit

For example I am in the "Show log" tab and see all changes between 2 branches and I need to merge only some of these changes. How to do it?

Comment: git cannot merge only separate files. git considers the whole commit.

Comment: is it possible to do it using any other mechanisms?

Comment: Do you want the log graph has the "merge" point? or just want to pick some changes?